# Javascript OR statment result different in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, operators

I have a problem with following code:

```
var status = null;
var action = 1;


function test() {
    if(status != null || action == 3) {
        alert('Why am i her?');
    }else {
        alert('I should be here');
    }
}

test();
```

I get expected results in Firefox and IE alert('I should be here'). But in Chrome i get alert('Why am i here?').

Comment: It works for me in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/9p3nA/ Version 33.0.1750.146 on Win7..

Comment: Yeah it works in jsfiddle, but try to paste this code to chrome javascript console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

status and action var names seem too good to not be system reserved. maybe your chrome has something running with a status var allocated. try changing them to something else and see if it makes a difference.

```
var myStatus = null;
var myAction = 1;


function test() {
    if(myStatus != null || myAction == 3) {
        alert('Why am i her?');
    }else {
        alert('I should be here');
    }
}

test();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce this for you, but I might just have the answer:

```
if(status !== null || action === 3) {
```

Compare the variable not just by value but also by type, by using an extra =

Comment: I tried in Firefox and Chromium both on linux and the default android browser on Samsung Note2 using  @Josh Crozier's example at http://jsfiddle.net/9p3nA